# Prove the internal energy of a rubber band is only a function of temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, energy, temperature

I need to prove that the internal energy of a rubber band that is stretched is only a function of its temperature, i.e.

[image] is equal to 0.

I found a way to prove it when the tension *f* is proportional to the temperature *T* if the length *L* is held constant. However, I have to prove this when the length *L* is proportional to the tension *f* and inversely proportional to the temperature *T*.

I think I'm supposed to make use of the fact that

[image].

That would get me this far. Using the 1st law of thermodynamics, *dU = TdS + fdL* and differentiating all terms w.r.t. *L*:

[image]

But how can I prove the T-term is equal to *f*?

Also, *f* can be expressed as

[image], where A is Helmholtz free energy and *l* = *L*.

Comment: Are you saying that you are allowed to assume that, at constant L, f is proportional to T?

Comment: The only sentence about proportionality is "We know the length of the rubber band is directly proportional to the tension applied on it and inversely proportional to its temperature T." So if L is proportional to f and inversely proportional to T, then that would mean f is inversely proportional to T.

Constant volume for the band and constant temperature for the surroundings are  assumed.

Answer (score 1):

From your "We know..." statement, $$L=k\frac{f}{T}$$or$$f=\frac{LT}{k}$$If you substitute this into your equation, you get the desired result.